# Un sens plus précis, l'usage, et le contexte du mot « râleur »

Tags: sens, usage, vocabulaire

Je cherche une explication plus précise du mot « *râleur* », y compris des exemples d'usage avec une explication du contexte des exemples.  Particulièrement, je me demande si on peut l'utiliser formellement ?

J'ai trouvé ce mot, [râleur](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/r%C3%A2leur), sur *WordReference* en cherchant un mot qui signifie « qui dérange constamment ».  Je le comprends comme un mot familier pour signifier :

> *qui se plaint facilement*. (De *WordReference*)

Je trouve que c'est difficile de comprendre le sens du mot avec cette définition.

Comment: http://cnrtl.fr/definition/raleur

Comment: Why the close votes? I can edit it to make it fit if I understand why.

Comment: All 3 close votes are for the following reason : *Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Do give context for where you heard or saw the word.*

Comment: @AlexisPigeon I edited the question, is it a better fit now?

Comment: IMHO, it was already ok in its original form. If the question ends up being closed anyway, you can ask for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C'est du registre familier, donc on évitera de l'utiliser dans un contexte plus formel.

Le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A2leur) fournit une définition semblable:

> Qui est porté à protester de façon hargneuse.

Mais il y a aussi un sens d'exagération, par le fait qu'un râleur se plaindra parfois (souvent?) pour des raisons pas vraiment justifiées.

Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A2leur) propose d'ailleurs une très jolie définition

> Qui manifeste souvent et mal à propos son mécontentement.

C'est à rapprocher de [*grognon*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grognon), [*bougon*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bougon), [*ronchon*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ronchon), [*rouspéteur*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rousp%C3%A9teur), qui sonnent à mon avis un peu plus polis, mais ont un sens moins fort.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne peux pas commenter la réponse de @Alexis Pigeon mais je rajouterais que dernière j'entends souvent râler (à l'oral) dans le sens de "déconner, parler pour rien dire, dire n'importe quoi".

Answer (score 0):

Un exemple, "Paul, attendait son tour pour envoyer un colis à la poste. Il y passe plus de 20 minutes et se plaint du service. En rentrant chez lui il passe tout le chemin à pester contre la poste. Devant sa maison, il croise son facteur et lui demande pourquoi il n'est pas venu plus tôt? Quel râleur !".